# How to give language preference in Microsoft Translator?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

Request:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/detect?api-version=3.0" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <client-secret>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[{'Text':'No'}]"
```

Response:

```
[{"language":"es","score":1.0,"isTranslationSupported":true,"isTransliterationSupported":false}]
```

What I am able to understand is that the word "No" is same in both languages English and Spanish but is there any way to tell Translator that if conflicts occurs then prefer English.

Comment: No that's not supported. We recommend using longer sentences with detect api, to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect api does not support setting a preference for language when multiple languages are possible. We recommend using longer sentences to get a more accurate result.